# Zurb Foundation rendering binary output for database image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a Web API action `db-image` that returns a `HttpResponseMessage` object with image bytes fetched from database:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
BinaryImage image = GetImage(id);
byte[] imageBytes = image.Bytes;
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(image.MimeType);
result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

When using this action with regular HTML `<img>` tag, the actual image is rendered

```
<img src="/db-image/12976/golf-course" alt="golf course" />
```

But when the same action url is used in a `div` with Zurb Foundation CSS `data-interchange` property, it renders binary output

```
<div class="bg-img-class" data-interchange="[/db-image/12976/golf-course, small], [/db-image/12976/golf-course, medium]"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EIDT**: Even the `div` tag is displaying the actual image when used **without** Zurb Foundation's interchange.

```
<div class="bg-img-class" style="background-image:url('/db-image/12976/golf-course')"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using an image tag in your HTML example but a DIV tag with your Foundation example?  According to the docs(https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/interchange.html), the DIV element is used for swapping entire chunks of HTML or background images.  The base example in the docs uses an IMG tag for the base usage example.  Does `interchange` work when you use the IMG tag?

Comment: I ask because the IMG tag instructs the browser to do different things than a DIV tag.  One attempts to render whatever it received as an Image, the other plain HTML.  I would wager your use of DIV vs IMG tags is causing your issues.  You could probably render a DIV tag with an IMG tag pointing to your endpoint and it would be successful.

Comment: @Tommy please see my edit

Comment: Starting to think it's a bug